# Generate Matrix NxN with no repeated elements per column and per row

Tags: python, numpy, matrix, python-itertools, brute-force

I would like to generate all possible matrix of size NxN such that there are no elements repeated in the rows neither on the columns. Also the matrix values must vary between 1 and N.
Is there an optimized way to do it?
The purpose of this is that every time I generate one of this matrix, I do a test to it to see if it checks some properties and, if it checks, I don't need to generate more matrixes.

Comment: You mean a magic square? Check out this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47834140/numpy-equivalent-of-matlabs-magic

Comment: can an element be repeated in the diagonal or somewhere else?

Comment: @NicolasGervais yes, it has to be something like [1, 2, 3, 4], 
 [3, 4, 1, 2], 
 [2, 3, 4, 1], 
 [4, 1, 2, 3]

Comment: @warped i meant something like these
[1, 2, 3, 4], [3, 4, 1, 2], [2, 3, 4, 1], [4, 1, 2, 3]

Comment: @warped I checked again the magic square and can I tell to the function with elements can be used to build up the sum I want? For example, in the last mensagem I gave u every row and column would have sum 10 but the elements inside can only be 1,2,3 or 4

Comment: Ok, so what you are looking for is a latin square. There are some answers here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49606404/efficient-way-of-generating-latin-squares-or-randomly-permute-numbers-in-matrix